# Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError wrong name: how to solve this?

Tags: java, gradle, directory, noclassdeffounderror

I have created a very simple `Java` application, and built it using `Gradle`.

It is an application with just the Standard "Hello World" Java class (shown below).

I have built it with Gradle successfully and my `.class` file has been created at the standard folder location:

`build>classes>main>my>package>HelloWorld.class`

However, when I navigate to this folder and run in `cmd line`:

```
java HelloWorld
```

I get the following **error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HelloWorld (wrong name: my/package/HelloWorld)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

**My HelloWorld.java**

```
package my.package;

public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

What is the cause of this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should run the command (in Windows)

```
java my\package\HelloWorld
```

from the directory `build/classes/main` and not from `build/classes/main/my/package`. This is because `HelloWorld` class declares that it resides in the package `my.package` with `package my.package;`.

Comment: Whenever I load this project in Intelij and try to create a Configuration to run it, it does not save the configuration? Do you know the reason for this?

Comment: More info: when I try to compile module I get "Unable to make the module, related gradle configuration not found" ?

Comment: @java123999 Could you create another question for that? It is not related to this problem. But, first, make sure Gradle is properly configured in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to run from the same folder:

- First way:

  - delete the `package my.package` line
  - compile your code with `javac HelloWorld.java`
  - run your code with `java HelloWorld`
- Second way: Run straight away

  - `java -cp . HelloWorld.java`